# Validate string with regular expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I just wanted to ask for an example of a regular expression, that would match the below string format for `JS:`

```
2 or 2/3 or 2/4/1 or 5/6/7/4, etc.
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `/^(\d\/?)+$/` ? but it's hard to tell your exact criteria from just couple examples...

Comment: `/^(\d+\/)*\d+$/.test('2/4/6')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var regex = /^(\d+\/)*\d+$/;
```

- `^` - start of the string
- `$` - end of the string
- `(\d+\/)*` zero or more instances of digits followed by `/`
- `\d+` - one or more digits

Comment: Works perfectly! (-: Thank you so much. –  Arun P Johny